# VBS objFSO.GetFile returning File Not Found error

Tags: c#, excel, vbscript

I have a simple vbscript that returns the date last modified of an excel file. The script has worked well for the last few years, but my updated application is now written in C# and on a 64bit server. The OLD SCRIPT below now errors on line 3 with "\servernamesharedfolderfile.xls file not found". I revised the script to NEW SCRIPT below, but now receive "file not found" on line 3. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

OLD SCRIPT:

```
dim lastmod

Set objFSO = Createobject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("\\servername\sharedfolder\file.xls")   
lastmod = objFile.DateLastModified

Result = datevalue(lastmod)
```

NEW SCRIPT:

```
dim lastmod

Set objFSO = Createobject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("\\\servername\\sharedfolder\\file.xls")   
lastmod = objFile.DateLastModified

Result = datevalue(lastmod)
```

Comment: Are you sure the account that the script is running under has access to that server, share, and file?

Comment: Why are you doubling up on the backslashes?

Comment: @DavidCrowell The OP explained that, the older version contained `\servernamesharedfolderfile.xls` which OP assumed was removing the singular backslashes in the string, so they doubled them to attempt a real network path.

Comment: @Rich, assuming this is still VBScript, the "new script" is invalid and the "old script" works.  OP mentions a C# application, but I see no C# code here.

Comment: We have a web application (vendor maintained) that has a vbscript tool that allows us to add button controls to the screens in the web application. The web application was written in Delphi code and the vendor performed a refactored .NET/C# code to the web application. Also the web application was running on a windows 2003 32bit server and it now runs on a windows 2008 64bit server. Either the new 2008 64bit server or the refactored .NET/C# code is causing this issue when executing button control containing the vbscript. It's removing a '\' from the unc path and adding an extra'\' doesn't help

Comment: How do you activate the vbs? Directly to the file or through wscript/cscript? Because 64 bit servers cant run vbs directly, you have to go through c:\windows\syswow64\ more info on that in the vbscript info section.

Comment: If C# is involved here (somehow, I'm still a little lost on that) and it's converting your double slashes to single slashes then you need to use FOUR slashes at the start of your servername (`\\\\servername`) and double slashes for the rest (`\\\\server\\path\\file.xls`). It looks like you're using three slashes before the server name in your "New Script" code above.